# Getting a TypeError when fetching from Google Vision API

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, typeerror, google-vision

So I'm trying to take a picture and populate the data in a list in a new screen. I'm getting a TypeError after I snap the picture.
`Error [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'jsonRes.responses[0]')]`

Here is my code:

```
  detectText(base64) {
    fetch("https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=" + GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "requests": [{
            "image": { "content": base64 },
            "features": [
                { type: "TEXT_DETECTION" }
            ]}]
      })
    })
    .then(response => { return response.json() }) 
    .then(jsonRes => {
      let text = jsonRes.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation.text
      this.props.navigation.navigate('ContactScreen', { text: text })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Error', err)
    })
  }
```

When I snap the picture, the data should be gathered in a picker select list.
Has been super frustrating and been trying for over 2 hours now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought, but that error implies `response.json()` returned `undefined`. Was the API call actually successful (status code 200, etc)? According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), `fetch` doesn't fail its promise on an unsuccessful call (e.g. status code 400).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Google Vision API was changed recently. Issue resolved.